# if-condition with previously unknown set of varibles

Tags: r

*I did not find an answer to this - in my opinion quite basic - question. So in case I missed out on an already existing solution, I am sorry for that and would appreciate a link to the thread.*

I am facing the following problem:

I want to create an if-condition whether or not an observations fulfills certain criteria. However, the set of variables i want to test is unknown, as they are created in the process and might change, depending on the data fed into the model.

I now have hard-coded the variable names, like below:

```
data$selectvar <- ifelse(data$crit1 == 1 | data$crit2 == 1 | data$crit3 == 1, 1, 0)
```

In above example, there could be cases where e.g., I only have `crit1` and `crit3` in the data set `data`, but not `crit2`. So the if condition would throw an error in these cases.

The way I have named the variables is that they all have the same prefix, so maybe there is a way to work with `grepl` or similar, but I don't know how.

Comment: check out `contains` or `starts_with` from `dplyr` maybe?

Comment: `data[grepl("^crit", names(data))] == 1`?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! Stupid question, but what is the function of `^`?

Comment: Also, if someone faces a similar problem, below the code I used which seems to work fine for that purpose (I had to use `any`):

`dat$selectvar <- ifelse(any(dat[grepl("^crit", names(dat))]) == 1, 1, 0)`

Comment: I'm glad you figured out that you needed `any` around it. The `"^"` is part of *regular expressions*, and it indicates "start of string". For example, with that pattern, `"crit5"` would match but not `"acrit6"`. It might not be necessary, it's really difficult to provide rock-solid suggestions using regular expressions when nothing is known about the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, but if you want to use ifelse then you can try this..

```
ifelse(data[,grep("crit",colnames(data))]==1,1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks! for me the problem is that if I use this function, it seems to work only for the first column with that string, if the others are `TRUE`, the output column is still `0`. If I add `any()` it seems to work properly (see comment under the original question).